# Do I need to tape inside corners where tile will be set on one wall?

Tags: drywall, tile, taping

I am planning on tiling a Denshield wall which is surrounded by two finished drywall walls (inner corners). Do I need to tape the edges, or am I ok with a bead of silicone?

Comment: **"Do I need to tape the edges"**  By edge do you mean the corner were the denshield meets the drywall ? How does the tile interact with the drywall, does it just but up to it, any trim piece or just grout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the following scenario, I don't think taping offers much. If there's movement in the framing at the corner, tape isn't going to help. Your plan to caulk is probably fine. I'm not sure I'd use silicone, though. It's not paintable. An acrylic-silicone blend or flexible grout would be better.

```
 ____________________________________
|  |                            ^--backer board
|  |    tile                     
|--|______________________
| ^--caulk
|
|<-- existing painted drywall
|
|
```

Answer (score 2):

I usually do tape with fiber tape and thinset , this helps to lock everything together and the corner grout between the tiles won’t crack as easily or often.

Comment: You can't really run fiber tape and thinset onto a finished painted wall.